# .htaccess - redirect to specific page + redirect to /

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i'm trying to write a decent .htaccess for my website, without success.

My problem is that i want to redirect only some page to another page of another domain. All other requests must be redirected to / other domain.

I give you an example for more clarity:

I would like to redirect only:

```
www.foo.com/test_a.php => www.bar.com/newcategory/newpage
www.foo.com/another_page.php => www.bar.com/anothernewcategory/anothernewpage
```

all other request must be redirected to www.bar.com

Example:

```
www.foo.com/some_another_page_not_listed_above => www.bar.com
```

This is my .htaccess, but it don't works:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^/test_a.php
RewriteRule www.bar.com/newcategory/newpage/ [NC,L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^/another_page.php 
RewriteRule www.bar.com/anothernewcategory/anothernewpage/ [NC,L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^/  
RewriteRule https://www.bar.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Rule 1 and 2 works. Rule 3 no. For example if i go to www.foo.com/test_page i don't be redirected.

Where i wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try this?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^test_a.php http://www.bar.com/newcategory/newpage/ [NC,L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^another_page.php http://www.bar.com/anothernewcategory/anothernewpage/ [NC,L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^ https://bar.com [L,R=301]
```

Comment: @Simone Giusti: sorry, please retry my .htaccess above. It should now work.

Comment: @SimoneGiusti : I tested the one I edited above and it works perfectly. Please try it and let me know still can't make it work.

Comment: @SimoneGiusti: I also posted your real .htaccess after correcting and tested it again :)